# Can a number written using one hundreds 0's, one hundred 1's and one hundred 2's be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Question: Can a number written using one hundreds 0's, one hundred 1's and
one hundred 2's be a perfect square?

I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** All squares are equivalent to $0$, $1$, $4$, or $7$ modulo $9$.  Equivalently, all squares have digital roots (successive sums of digits until only a single digit remains) of $1$, $4$, $7$, or $9$.

ETA: Alternatively, ask yourself the following questions: Is my number divisible by $3$?  Is it divisible by $9$?  Are these answers possible for a square number?

Comment: ok. so now i know it has to end with 1. Where do I go from there?

Comment: What?  No—Compute the digital root of any number that has a hundred $0$'s, a hundred $1$'s, and a hundred $2$'s (and, one assumes, no other digits).  For instance, the digital root of $28^2 = 784$ is computed as follows: $7+8+4 = 19$, then $1+9 = 10$, then $1+0 = 1$.  What is the digital root of your hypothetical number?

Comment: I've added another hint that may provide a different way to the answer.